# Don't understand the parameters of checkAndGetNextWatermark method in AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks

Tags: apache-flink

Following is the javadoc for the AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks and checkAndGetNextWatermark

```
 *
 * <p>Timestamps and watermarks are defined as {@code longs} that represent the
 * milliseconds since the Epoch (midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC).
 * A watermark with a certain value {@code t} indicates that no elements with event
 * timestamps {@code x}, where {@code x} is lower or equal to {@code t}, will occur any more.
 *
 * @param <T> The type of the elements to which this assigner assigns timestamps.
 *
 * @see org.apache.flink.streaming.api.watermark.Watermark
 */
@Deprecated
public interface AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks<T> extends TimestampAssigner<T> {

    /**
     * Asks this implementation if it wants to emit a watermark. This method is called right after
     * the {@link #extractTimestamp(Object, long)} method.
     *
     * <p>The returned watermark will be emitted only if it is non-null and its timestamp
     * is larger than that of the previously emitted watermark (to preserve the contract of
     * ascending watermarks). If a null value is returned, or the timestamp of the returned
     * watermark is smaller than that of the last emitted one, then no new watermark will
     * be generated.
     *
     * <p>For an example how to use this method, see the documentation of
     * {@link AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks this class}.
     *
     * @return {@code Null}, if no watermark should be emitted, or the next watermark to emit.
     */
    @Nullable
    Watermark checkAndGetNextWatermark(T lastElement, long extractedTimestamp);
}
```

For the parameters of checkAndGetNextWatermark method, say, I have 4 records :A、B、C、D that comes in order(A first, D last),
When I ask the watermak for record C, are the following two statements correct?

1. `lastElement` refers to record B
2. `extractedTimestamp` refers to the timestamp of record C

Also, I would ask why `lastElement` is needed for the checkAndGetNextWatermark method?

I see serveral places in our team's code that extract timestamp from lastElement when implementing the checkAndGetNextWatermark method, which is wrong if the above two statements are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastElement` refers to record C. It's something of a misnomer; it's called the *last* element because watermark handling is done after the record has been processed.

Comment: I did a quick testing and it works as your answer says, thanks!